# How to make a url virtual 'directory' based on unique Ids

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, directory

Lets start with an example: I want to do what Tumblr is doing. More specifically, every time you click on the 'reblog' button, the URL changes to something like *"/reblog/UNIQUEID/UNIQUEID/"*.
Yet obviously they don't have millions of directories with html files in each.

So I was wondering, if I want to make a something similar how would I approach it?
We can get the Unique ID via PHP GET and then using JavaScript change the URL to display it as *"/dir/uniqueId"* instead of *"/dir?=uniqueId"* but that seems very cumbersome.

And if we do that, it also posses a new question: what if a user enters *"/dir/uniqueId"* in the URL bar... that wouldn't work because its an edited string from JavaScript.

---

I'm not familiar with htaccess, yet I'm pretty sure it has a huge implication on the answers.

So, how would one go about fixing this problem of terrible url syntax (?= etc) to something that looks more like directories, but fundamentally isn't?

Recap:
**How does one make /dir/uniqueId work while using PHP/htaccess but the uniqueId are not directories or actual files**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example...

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^reblog/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?reblog=$1 [L]
```

**index.php**

```
if (isset($_GET['reblog'])) {
    $uniqueId = $_GET['reblog'];

    //Do some stuff with that $uniqueId
}
```

**url example**

```
http://www.somesite.com/reblog/foo123bar
```

You can build from this example to match your requirements. As your question stands now, it's too broad to provide a more specific answer.